# How to convert Apr 1/2020 to 2020-04-01

Tags: date, format

How do I convert Apr 1/2020 to 2020-04-01 in excel?

I tried all of the helps by Microsoft and used format cell for dates. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CDate`:

```
TrueDate = CDate("Apr 1/2020")

? TrueDate
2020-04-01
```